# Please help me undelete this Community♦-deleted question

Tags: support, status-completed, deleted-questions, vote-to-undelete, abandoned-questions

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48460942/how-and-when-should-i-use-posix-c-source-in-c-programs) and somehow missed the fact that it was answered. A few days ago the question got automatically deleted (RemoveAbandonedQuestions). But I want to add a comment as well as upvote the answer. Please help me to undelete the question.

Comment: This question is not covered by "can no longer be reproduced". That is for bugs and other concerns that literally cannot happen ever again due to fundamental changes in the system, like bugs from the old Documentation module, which has been removed from the site. The situation mentioned by the OP could return if their question gets Roomba'd again. Voting to reopen.

Comment: @RobertColumbia I think the same should be right also for the recently closed around 700 docSE-related questions. I am not sure, if it was a good idea (although I've cooperated with that project, but I was not sure even then).

Comment: @RobertColumbia: I don't understand why this couldn't have gotten an answer saying "question was reopened", which I could accept.